# Please help me understand the solution of this question!

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question : Six bells commence tooling together and toll at intervals 2,4,6,8,10,12 minutes.In 30 hours,how many times do they toll together?

I found the LCM of 2,4,6,8,10,12 minutes in order to find the minimum minutes after they will tool together.

LCM (2,4,6,8,10,12)=120

It means they will toll together after 2 hours that is 120 mins.So in in 30 hours they should too together **15 times**( 30/2).

But the answer provided in the textbook is 16 times.Can you please explain how they got 16?

Comment: Seems like you made a [Fencepost error](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have committed a fencepost (or Obi-wan) error. The question implies that the bells ring together at the very start of the $30$-hour period; $15$ periods of $120$ minutes pass, and then they ring together again at the very end of the $30$ hours. So they ring together $15+1=16$ times.

Comment: Please strive not to post more dupe answers to FAQs. Rather, please help organize and improve prior answers.

Comment: @BillDubuque I can't. The other answers already _are_ organised.

Comment: Presumably you *can* resist answering dupes, and instead locate and link to dupes, and post answers in the dupes if you have anything novel to add.